# Let $f : E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Show that if $|f|$ is measurable on $E$ and the set $\{f > 0\}$ is measurable, then $f$ is measurable on $E$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I'm learning about Measure Theory (specifically measurable functions) and need help with the following problem:

> Let $f : E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Show that if $|f|$ is measurable on $E$ and the set $\{f > 0\}$ is measurable, then $f$ is measurable on $E$.

---

What I don't understand is that the implication $$|f| \ \text{measurable}  \implies f \ \text{measurable} \ \ (1)$$ is clearly false.

For example, let $A$ be a non-measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and let $f$ be the function $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1\text{ if }x\in A,\\ -1\text{ if }x\notin A.\end{cases}$$

Then $f$ is not measurable ($f^{-1}[\{1\}] = A$) but $|f|$ is measurable (it's the constant function $1$).

---

How does the additional condition that $\{f > 0\}$ is measurable makes the implication $(1)$ true and how do I prove it?

Comment: The complement is then also measurable.

Comment: Consider $f_+ := |f|\cdot\chi_{\{f>0\}}$, where $\chi_A$ is the characterisitc function of a set $A$. What is $f_+$? Can you also define some $f_-$? Can you combine $f_+$ and $f_-$ to get $f$?

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp I understood your first comment, it is helpful. For your second comment, the definition I'm familiar for $f_+$  and $f_-$ are as follows: $f_+(x) = f(x)$ if $x \in \{f(x) > 0\}$ and 0 otherwise. Similarly $f_-(x) = |f(x)|$ if $x \in \{f(x) < 0\}$ and 0 otherwise. We also have the identity $f = f_+ - f_-$ but I don't know how I should combine all those to prove the given statement.

Comment: Your $f_+$ and my $f_+$ are the same! The characteristic function of a measurable set is measurable and $|f|$ is. So...? Do you know that the product of measurable functions is measurable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I make my comment an answer. I assume that you know that product and sum of two measurable functions is again measurable. Define $f_+ := \max\{f,0\} = |f|\cdot\chi_{\{f>0\}}$. This function is measurable. Also, define $f_- := \min\{f,0\} = (-|f|)\cdot\chi_{\{f\le 0\}}$. Also this function is measurable. So, $f = f_+ + f_-$ is measurable.

EDIT: To see that $\chi_A$ is measurable for each measurable set $A$, you only have to realize that $\chi_A^{-1}(B)$ can only be equal to $\emptyset$, the whole measurable space $E$, $A$ or $E\setminus A$ (depending on whether $0\in B$ or $1\in B$).

Comment: One more question (just to be sure): $f_-$ is measurable since it is equal to $|f|$ for $x \in \{f(x) < 0\}$ and $|f|$ is measurable by assumption. Is that correct?

Comment: My point was that $f_-$ is measurable because it is the product of the two measurable functions $-|f|$ and $\chi_{\{f\le 0\}}$.

Comment: Great (I just saw the edit)! Thank you for your detailed and clear explanation (and your time). It was extremely helpful and understandable. It also gave me a new way of thinking about these problems.

Comment: I am really happy that I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have that

if $b \geq 0, f^{-1}(]b,a[) = (|f|)^{-1}(]b,a[) \cap \{f > 0 \}$, so it's measurable

if $b < 0, f^{-1}(]b,0]) = (|f|)^{-1}([0,-b[ ) \cap \{f > 0 \}^c$, so it's also measurable

This imply that if $a>0, b<0$,  $f^{-1}(]b,a[) = f^{-1}(]0,a[) \cup f^{-1}(]b,0])$ is measurable

if $a < 0, b<a, f^{-1}(]b,a[) = (|f|)^{-1}(]-a,-b[) \cap \{f > 0 \}^c$, so it's also measurable

hence $f^{-1}(]b,a[)$ is measurable for all $a>b$

Comment: Your first two statements seem to be false.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp :Let $a > b > 0$, then if $f(x) \in ]a,b[$, then $|f(x)| \in ]a,b[$ and $f(x) > 0$, so $f^{-1}(]a,b[) \subset (|f|)^{-1}( ]a,b[ ) \cap \{f>0\}$, and if $f(x) > 0$ and $|f(x)| \in ]a,b[$, then $f(x) \in ]a,b[$, so $ (|f|)^{-1}( ]a,b[ ) \cap \{f>0\} \subset f^{-1}(]a,b[) $

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp : but there was a mistake in the second one

Comment: If $a > b$ then $]a,b[ = \emptyset$.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp : I'm tired, and my lateralization problems striked again.  inverted the left and right numbers :p I'll correct