# Example that if |f| is measurable, then f is not necessarily

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

Problem: Give example where $\left|f\right|$ is $\mathcal{A}$-measurable
but $f$ is not $\mathcal{A}$-measurable. This problem is related to the following two:

[Let $f : E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Show that if $|f|$ is measurable on $E$ and the set $\{f > 0\}$ is measurable, then $f$ is measurable on $E$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1716430/let-f-e-rightarrow-mathbbr-show-that-if-f-is-measurable-on-e-and)

[If |f| is (lebesgue) measurable, is f measurable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2212495/if-f-is-lebesgue-measurable-is-f-measurable)

But I think my stated problem is more simple. Is my reasoning (below) correct (even though it is sloppy)? Is it possible to make my proof more "rigorous"?

My attempt: define $E_{a}=\left\{ x:-a\le x\le a\right\} $. Let $\mathcal{A}$
be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra generated from the collection $\left\{ E_{a}:a\in\mathbb{R}\right\} $.
Then $\left(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{A}\right)$ is a measurable space.
Define $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ to be $f(x)=x$. Consider
the set $G=(-\infty,b]$ for a specific $b<0$ (say). I now try to
prove that $G\not\in\mathcal{A}$. Let's see what the intersection-criteria
of a $\sigma$-algebra can do.

For any collection $E_{a_{1}},E_{a_{2}},\ldots,E_{a_{\infty}}$, where
$a_{i}\in\mathbb{R}$, consider that

$\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}E_{a_{i}}=E_{\sup a_{i}}$

Clearly, $G\ne E_{\sup a_{i}}$ for any sequence $\left\{ a_{i}\right\} $.

Similarly, the $E_{a}^{c}$ won't help, as any countable union or
intersection of $E_{a_{i}}$ and $E_{b_{i}}^{C}$ will either be the
empty set or will have a real number on both sides of 0, so it is
impossible that it could equal $G$. Thus $G\not\in\mathcal{A}$ and so $f$ is not $\mathcal{A}$-measurable.

Comment: How does this prove that $(-\infty,-1]$ is not in the sigma-algebra generated by the intervals $[-a,a]$ with $a$ nonnegative?

Comment: Re the problem of whether this duplicates previous questions, note that previous answers give, for every sigma-algebra $\mathcal F\ne2^\mathbb R$, some non $\mathcal F$-measurable function $f$ such that $|f|$ is $\mathcal F$-measurable. You seem to be asking whether your proof that $f=\mathrm{Id}$ is not measurable for a specific sigma-algebra, is correct.

Comment: @Did that was what I tried to claim with the unions of the $E_{a_i} $. I tried to use the criteria of sigma algebra to show that you cannot generate a set like $(-\infty,-1)$ from only the sets $E_a$. I would be curious to see a better way since I also feel my way is not rigorous. But I wanted to show my work.

Comment: @Did Yes it is for the proof I have attempted. I will try to clean it up a bit. One of the specific questions I asked is indeed covered in the other link..

Comment: To show your work is (more than) ok, of course. But I was trying to understand how you think the steps you explain show (or lead to a proof) that $(-\infty,-1]$ is not in the sigma-algebra.

Comment: @Did I was trying to show that any set in the sigma algebra must have both positive and negative numbers, and since $(-\infty,-1)$ has only negative numbers, it cannot be in the sigma algebra. But I could not find a way to prove that clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a shortcut for proving that sets like $(-\infty,b]$ will not belong to the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the sets of the form $[-a,a]$.

Let $\mathcal V\subset\wp(\mathbb R)$ denote the collection of sets $S$ that satisfy $x\in S\implies-x\in S$ for every $x\in\mathbb R$.

Then $\mathcal V$ is evidently a $\sigma$-algebra.

Also evident is that $\mathcal V$ contains all sets of the form $[-a,a]$.

This together allows the conclusion that $\mathcal A\subseteq\mathcal V$ where $\mathcal A$ denotes the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing these sets.

Finally it is evident that $(-\infty,b]\notin\mathcal V$ hence $(-\infty,b]\notin\mathcal A$.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. I think I was approach it from the wrong side. You instead made a sigma algebra and showed that the sets $E_a$ are in it. I was trying to start with the sets $E_a$, which made things more complicated. I will study your proof more.